# Book trilogy about teenagers with superpowers in an industrialization like era

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I'm trying to figure out the name of a trilogy of books I read 7 to 10 years ago. I read the books in German and don't know if they where translations or what language they were originally written in. The German covers of all three books had silhouettes of industrial cities on them.

The protagonists of the books are two or three teenagers / young adults with special abilities. One of them is a boy that has the ability to teleport, he grew up in a rich family. There is also a girl that is superhuman fast and strong, she grew up in an orphanage.

The world of the series is simmilar to the real world during the industrialization in Europa (there are factories and Zeppelins,) but all the countries are fictional. Special abilities / super powers are not common or known about in that world.

Here are some other random details I remember:

- The first book starts with a prolog in which multiple families try to leave a snowed in and abandoned company town. All but one father are killed by wolves, he than finds a giant unnatural cave with a flower made of metal inside.
- The protagonists are all orphans or adopted. When searching for their biological parents they find out that they and other connected adults killed themself. One person then destroyed their heads and used an industrial press to destroy their own. Figuring out why they did that is a central part of the first book's plot.
- The protagonist have their special abilities because they are the children of adults with special abilities. Their parents and other adults got their abilities from interacting with those flowers made from metal. Interacting with one either gives someone special abilities or kills them (apparently random.)

Spoilers for the later books:

- > At some point one of the protagonists tries to hijack a Zeppelin loaded with the metal flowers. The captain throws the cargo overboard (without knowing what it is.) The flowers land in a city, kill many, and cause mayhem.
- > The man from the prolog is now the president / ruler of the country the story is set in. He gained special abilities from the metal flower and let other government officials interact with it as well. They have a sort of hive mind controlled by him.
- > He wants to keep giving people special abilities until someone gets the ability to resurrect his dead daughter whose body he preserved in ice.
- > Later it is revealed that the world of the book is the real world, but in the far future. Sometime around the modern era the special ability granting metal flower was discovered and some people got special abilities. Then a nuclear war happend and reset civilization. Some of the people with special abilities from the modern era are still alive.
- > One man from the modern era lives in a parallel dimension created by a woman from the modern era with extremely strong abilities.

Comment: How did the parents manage to crush their own heads?  With psionic powers?  By crushing them in their own hands?  By using a machine?  Did they all use the same method, or did they have different ways of achieving the result?

Comment: @DavidW They killed themself using mundane ways. I believe one of them destroyed the other ones heads (after they were dead) and then killed themself with an industrial press. I have updated the question to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trilogy is [Morland](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60553-morland) by Peter Schwindt and the three books are named [Die Rückkehr der Eskatay](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6330954-die-r-ckkehr-der-eskatay), [Die Blume des Bösen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7139841-die-blume-des-b-sen), and [Das Vermächtnis der Magier](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8370372-das-verm-chtnis-der-magier).

It seems like the books were written in German and never translated.

German Goodreads summary of the first book:

> "Verschwinde!", kreischte Phineas und hob abwehrend die Hände. "Ich will dich hier nicht mehr sehen, hörst du? Du bist ein gottverdammter Eskatay!" Er spuckte dieses Wort regelrecht aus. "Ein Eskatay?", fragte Tess hilflos. "Was soll das sein?" "Ein Teufel in Menschengestalt! Das Böse schlechthin." Phineas' Gesicht war zu einer Fratze verzerrt.
>
> Vor vielen Tausend Jahren vernichteten die Menschen Morlands alle magischen Begabten. Sie fühlten sich sicher. Doch nun sind die Eskatay zurück.

Google translated:

> "Get out!" Phineas shrieked and raised his hands defensively. "I don't want to see you here anymore, you hear me? You're a goddamned Eskatay!" He practically spat out the word. "An Eskatay?" Tess asked helplessly. "What's that supposed to be?" "A devil in human form! Evil par excellence." Phineas' face was twisted into a grimace.
>
> Many thousands of years ago, the people of Morland destroyed all those gifted with magic. They felt safe. But now the Eskatay are back.

After thinking about it for some time I remembered the title and searched for images on google until I recognized the cover.

Comment: Thank you for your self-answer! You will be able to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons tomorrow.

Comment: The story was also available as radio play in the ARD Audiothek pool.